# how to export output from powershell to csv?

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a long powershell output in two columns:

```
edgeitem           #text
1.1              562
1.2              ben
1.3              smith
1.4              play.inc 
2.1              791
2.2              tom
2.3              jones
2.4              jm pty ltd
 .                  .
 .                  .
 .                  .
 .                  .
```

How do I export all the values in the text column to a single column in a csv file? I've looked at Export.csv but it asks for an input object and I don't know how to call this column as the object. The outputs are extracts from a bunch of xml files if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might wanna explore on Export-Csv `Get-Help Export-Csv` its a function which will help you do it